# PHP __atuoload function not working on Linux (developed on Windows)

Tags: php, linux, windows, pdo

I have a small database application which uses a custom class to connect to a database using `PDO`.

This application was developed on xampp, then I loaded it up to a Linux server where it worked fine. I then made a local Windows copy and reworked some things.

Now the database isn't connecting and I think it is because the autoload fucntion in php is not working.

The function changed from loading a few php files to loading a directory full of classes. I don't have the original functions, but it currently looks like this:

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    $filename = 'classes/' . str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, strtolower($class_name)).'.php';
    include $filename;
};
```

Everything works fine until I loaded it into my Ubuntu server. I can no longer access the class to connect to the database. I assume it has something to do with directory names but I am inexperienced on Linux. Is this not pointing to anything?

Comment: Are you aware that in linux (to be precise - in native linux filesystems) filenames are case-sensitive?

Comment: I was not and removing `strtolower` solved the problem. Thanks a lot.